# ColdFusion SQL Server Error Too many open files error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have an API developed in ColdFusion 9 that continuously searches for items and inserts a record on the outcome of that search into a SQL Server 2008 table but I'm noticing a lot of errors in my Application log for the following error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: X.X.X.X:X. Reason: Too many open files. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: foo.cfm, line: 203
```

I realise there's not much to go on here but that's all the info I have from the logs.

Anyone have the faintest idea what might be going on?!

Comment: What does line 203 of foo.cfm do?

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error from using and old version of Lucene.  Because Lucene used an old version of apache commons io that would sometimes stop closing the file read by the Lucene Index.   So every time someone woul do a search a file would be opened and never closed.  Eventually we hit the file open limit which would cause various problem on the server.  One Of which is you can't connect to a datasource.

We had to bounce the server a couple times to release the open files.  And then we updated our Lucene software to the latest version.

I believe Lucene is what Solr runs on (the cf index).

This happened on a Linux machine and we were running java, not coldfusion (but cf runs on Java)